# Maestro detalle campo relacionado no lo puedo mostrar - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Muy buenos días, estoy teniendo un inconveniente al intentar traer un campo de una tabla relacionada para poder hacer un maestro detalle.

Estoy usando autenticacion de usuarios el cual tengo una clase base User que hereda de IdentityUser

```
public class User :IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "Document")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not have more than {1} characters.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    public string Document { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not have more than {1} characters.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not have more than {1} characters.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not have more than {1} characters.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

    public string FullNameWithDocument => $"{FirstName} {LastName} - {Document}";

    public Province Province { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

También tengo dos clases que tienen una relación con User (Client y Employye)

```
 public class Client 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Agenda> Agendas { get; set; }
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
}

 public class Employee 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Agenda> Agendas { get; set; }
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
}
```

Estas dos clases tienen entradas en Agenda osea, una cita en agenda tiene un cliente y un empleado asignado. 
El problema es cuando intento recuperar los registros en el maestro detalle, el cliente me lo trae sin problemas pero a la hora de traer el empleado el mismo me lo muestra null.

El controlador de details tiene el siguiente código

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var client = await _context.Clients
            .Include(c => c.User)
            .Include(c => c.DocumentType)
            .Include(c => c.Agendas)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (client == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(client);
    }
```

La vista es:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Agendas.FirstOrDefault().DateLocal)
        </th>
        <th>
            Empleado asignado
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Agendas)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateLocal)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aqui quiero mostrar el empleado)
            </td>

            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Agenda

```
public class Agenda
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd H:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is Available?")]
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd H:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateLocal => Date.ToLocalTime();
}
```

La idea es poder mostrar las fechas agendadas y que empleado está asignado pero como el empleado me llega nulo no lo veo 
Como se ve aquí debajo ni siquiera me aparece Employee
[image: Employee no aparece aquí]

Captura de pantalla 
[image: Vista Maestro detalle cliente]

desde ya muchísimas gracias 
saludos cordiales

Comment: Hola, por favor indica en la pregunta el código de la clase `Agendas`

Comment: ya mismo la mando

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes **bien construido** el **enlace relacional** en Entity Framework, mas concretamente en los datos que te de devuelve la tabla `Agenda`, los datos del empleado los puedes sacar de la propiedad `Employee` de la tabla `Agenda`.

En tu vista puedes acceder de esta manera:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.User.FullName)
```

Comment: No puedo hacer eso, no me deja acceder a Employee desde la vista. No sé qué más puedo hacer

Comment: @MarceloPírez: Pues entonce la tabla `Agenda` que has puesto en la pregunta está mal. Tienes una propiedad en la tabla `Agenda` que se llama `Employee`?. Si es así **item** es de tipo `Agenda` no?, entonces puedes acceder a la propiedad.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente logrado, creo que todos han contribuido y quizás no supe explicarme correctamente.

**En el controlador de Clientes**

```
 var client = await _context.Clients
            .Include(c => c.User)
            .Include(c => c.DocumentType)
            .Include(c => c.Agendas)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Employee.User)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

**En la Vista Details**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Agendas)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateLocal)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.User.FullName)
            </td>

            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

**Finalmente el resultado** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

GRACIAS A TODOS, SIGO APRENDIENDO CADA DIA

Comment: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, y marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.

Answer (score -2):

Si ese es todo el código... el fallo es que no estás buscando al empleado

```
var employee = await _context.Employees
            .Include(c => c.User)
            .Include(c => c.DocumentType)
            .Include(c => c.Agendas)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

pero tienes que ver que _context.Employees exista

Comment: Es que no me deja hacer un include de Employee no entiendo porqué

Comment: @MarceloPírez que error te lanza cuando lo intentas hacer?

Comment: cómo que no te deja? tienes definido _context.Employees?

Comment: Cuando intento hacer .Include(c => c.Employee) employee no existe, agrego una foto al final para que lo veas

Comment: Creo que no sabes muy bien lo que estás haciendo o yo lo estoy entendiendo mal. Tienes Employee, User y Client. Employee y Client NO están relacionados, así que no puedes incluir uno en el otro así. Saca los employee añadiendo el código que te he indicado y luego los emparejas con client según su cita en la agenda

Comment: si me enseñas la definición de agenda te saco el código